# Fill a DataGrid from two different sources?

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with 3 Columns. I would like to fill the first two columns from one SQL Table and the third column from a separate table. I can easily fill it from one source with a DataSet from my database as shown below, does anyone know how can I use two different sources?

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
da.Fill(ds);

dgUsers.DataSource = ds;
dgUsers.DataBind();
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You will have create a `DataTable` and manually fill the 3 fields from different sources and then make that DataTable as the source for datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Create a business object with three properties and create those objects from your data set. Use those business objects to populate your datagrid. Standard n-tier architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the two data sources.  With LINQ it looks like:

```
var query = from row in ds
                        join row2 in ds2 on row.value equals row2.value
                        select new { row.value, row.value2, row2.value3 };
```